# Typo in arduino-mega-2560 tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We have an [arduino-mega-2560](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/arduino-mega-2650/info) tag but we also have an incorrectly spelled [arduino-me**d**a-2560](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tags/arduino-meda-2650/info) tag (which unfortunately is used far more often than the correct tag).

Creating a synonym doesn't seem the way to go (since it's not a synonym, it's just incorrect) and there's nobody with enough score to do it. How can we get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I created the correct tag and synonym until we have someone that can fix this. I assumed that this would be an okay alternative since we do not have anyone, currently, that can fix these types of issues. If this is not a valid placeholder, please provide a comment/answer for a better alternative.

Comment: I was under the impression Robert Cartaino already fixed this. The faulty tag no longer exists.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the update. I didn't think anyone had access to those tools yet.